# How do you undo save changes to a project

Tags: rendering, animation, objects, smooth, saving

when u click on other and select something then it says save changes and you click on it, how do you undo this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Blender will save a backup of a previously-saved file when you save over it with the same file name.

If you go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open</kbd> and find your original file in the file selector, you can then click the <kbd>Filter</kbd> dropdown and check <kbd>Backup</kbd><kbd>.Blend</kbd><kbd>Files</kbd>, you'll see that the backup file is now shown in the file selector and you can click that to load it.

[image]

The default setting is for Blender to save one backup, but you can increase that number in Blender's Preferences if you have plenty of disk space by increasing the number under <kbd>Save</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>Load</kbd> > <kbd>Save</kbd><kbd>Versions</kbd>.

[image]