# Cant find backups of .blend files from months ago

Tags: blend-files, file-browser

So a couple of months ago I modeled a realistic human model but ended up redoing it in the same file, but looking back I wish I had the version of the model from 3 months ago, but in my autosaves folder, it only shows backups of it made after I had already remade the model. If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When there are no other files containing the version you want, I'm not sure what you expect us to do? Travel back in time to restore the files...?

Comment: Do you not have a blend1 file in the same folder as the original? - See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298904/how-do-you-undo-save-changes-to-a-project/298906#298906 This will only work if you haven't saved it more than once though assuming you have the default of one backup set.

Comment: impossible to recover if u kept overwrite-save it, especially for such a long time.